# Android InstaceID and unique app instance identification

Tags: android

I have been trying to understand this feature offered by the play services library:

https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation

Apparently you can uniquely identify an app installation with this ID. However, it is suggested that I keep this ID at the local storage of my application. This can be easily deleted by the user and then I would lose my installation ID.

Is there another way to uniquely identify an instance of your application?

Comment: Your app uses internal storage to store data, which is specific disk space partitioned for your app alone. In other words, the user can't go and delete individual files without deleting the app as a whole. So you shouldn't have to worry about your user messing with the files.

Comment: Once the user clears app data on the settings menu, all local data will be lost and, with it, my Instance ID.

Comment: And that would be correct behavior. If a user wishes to clear an app's data, they have that right, with the consequence of losing their personalized data. The user should always have control over the data and content on their device. If you are simply wanting a unique identifier for a user, using `Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID` is a decent choice.